# UILabel with an icon (UIImageView) inline, iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiimageview, uilabel

I'm working on a project that requires basically something like:

```
"text before [ICON] text after"
```

to display in a view controller.

I know in iOS7 you could do something with `NSTextAttachment`, but that is not available in iOS6.

Any suggestions?

*(if it matters: this label is going to support multiple languages as well).*

Comment: Is there a suitable emoji you can use instead of a custom icon?

Comment: @jeffamaphone It has to be a custom icon.